# Pandas MultiIndex get all rows with label value

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Assume you have a Panda DataFrame with a MultiIndex. You want to get all the rows that have a label with a particular value.  How do you do this?

My first thought was a boolean mask...

`df[df.index.labels == 1].head()`

but this does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: You can convert index back to columns and then filter. It certainly works with one index. It should work with multiindex but I am not sure.

Comment: Show the dataframe your working with.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Is this clearly documented somewhere? Is it unclear? Is it not helpful? It would have helped me obviously http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question

Comment: I wasn't the one who down voted, nor do I know who did.  But I can say that I've seen this question many times and has been answered many times.  Try http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pandas+filter+rows.  Someone probably didn't think you put enough effort into the research.  If you hover over the down vote button, it says "this question doesn't show any research effort".  Hope that helps.

Comment: You don't have a sample dataframe to work on.

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks for your input.  None of those results discuss filtering by label of a MultiIndex as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`xs` (cross-section)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]], columns=list("ABC")).set_index(["A", "B"])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
     C
A B
1 2  3
3 4  5
```

then you can take those which have level A equal to 1:

```
In [13]: df.xs(key=1, level="A")
Out[13]:
   C
B
2  3
```

Using `drop_level=False` does the filter (without dropping the A index):

```
In [14]: df.xs(key=1, level="A", drop_level=False)
Out[14]:
     C
A B
1 2  3
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify which index you use. In my example I took the second index (My dataframe is s because it was so in Multiindex page of Pandas):

```
s[s.index.labels[1]==1]
```

You can actually see how index is constructed if you type:

```
s.index
```

The resulting structure is:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], [1, 2]],
       labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
       names=['first', 'second'])
```

Below I have the full code:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
...           [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]]
... 
>>> tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
>>> index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
>>> s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=index)
>>> s[s.index.labels[1]==1]
first  second
bar    2        -0.304029
baz    2        -1.216370
foo    2         1.401905
qux    2        -0.411468
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

alternative solution:

```
In [62]: df = pd.DataFrame({'idx1': ['A','B','C'], 'idx2':[1,2,3], 'val': [30,10,20]}).set_index(['idx1','idx2'])

In [63]: df
Out[63]:
           val
idx1 idx2
A    1      30
B    2      10
C    3      20

In [64]: df[df.index.get_level_values('idx2') == 2]
Out[64]:
           val
idx1 idx2
B    2      10

In [65]: df[df.index.get_level_values(1) == 2]
Out[65]:
           val
idx1 idx2
B    2      10
```